# jQuery that do document.location = "url"

Tags: jquery, download, file-transfer

jQuery have many features for ajax requests, but if i want to download the response from the server the browser is not showing the download dialog if i do it using `$.ajax`

This works just fine:

```
document.location = 'VCard.aspx?name=Andreas'
```

In my responce from the server a set these to headers:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/x-vcard";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=vcard.vcf");
```

But if i do like this the download dialog don't show, the download works but the dialog don't show.

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/VCard.aspx',
    data: { name: 'Andreas' }
});
```

My `data:` contains of more then 40 different parameters and i want to use the json syntax to build the arguments to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajax` will use an `XMLHttpRequest` object to post the data. This will not trigger browser UI, since it's expected that it will be scripted.

If you just want a properly formatted querystring from an object, you can use [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Answer (score 0):

The $.ajax method is used to get data back from your server not show a dialog. You can have the ajax method show a dialog by doing something in the success action

```
$.ajax({
   type: POST,
   url: '/VCard.aspx’,
   data: { name: 'Andreas' }, 
   success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     /*open your dialog*/
   }
});
```